# Why isn't my catch block catching when I add an if statement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, try-catch

I have an onSubmit function in my React/Typescript app that will only hit my catch if I don't have my isValid check.  I have validation set up on both the client side and server side.  The catch displays the validation method from the back end.  If isValid is true the form should be submitted.  If isValid is false the form should not be submitted and it should hit my catch and display the validation errors.

The following code doesn't catch.  It won't submit because it is invalid but it also isn't showing the validation errors from the backend that it should.

```
    const onSubmit = async (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const isValid = formValidation();
        const baseUrl = getBackendUrl();
       
        try {
            
            if (isValid)
            {
                const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
            await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/api/enterprises/${enterpriseId}/users`, formData, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                }
            })
                .then(res => {
                    setFormData(res.data);
                    close();
                })
            }
            
        }
        catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
            }
        }
    };
```

If I do this:

```
const onSubmit = async (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        formValidation();
        const baseUrl = getBackendUrl();
        debugger;
        try {
            
                const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
            await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/api/enterprises/${enterpriseId}/users`, formData, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            })
                .then(res => {
                    setFormData(res.data);
                    close();
                })
            }
            
        }
        catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
            }
        }
    };
```

The errors from the backend show, but it will allow me to submit an invalid form.

Comment: You have check for `if (error.response) {`. It might be possible that error is thrown but error.response is undefiend. That is why setErrors(...) is not getting triggered.

Comment: Yes I get a 400 if I don't have the isValid check..if I have the isValid check it doesn't hit the catch.

Comment: Hope the problem is resolved ?

Comment: @ahmed it is, but not what I expected.  How I had it originally will work with the isValid...I don't need to display the server side responses to the user like I had thought.  Thank you for checking.

Comment: You need to handle your local validations and server side validations separately. You should have handles for both of these callbacks. I am not sure which form library are you using. They provide exact bindActions for redux if you want to change the state of errors. please check your documentation of form.